why does my nexon petrol have a sudden drop in mileage of after servicing
I have been servicing my Nexon (petrol) regularly since I bought it in 2021.Also checks Nitrogen pressure in tyres regularly
After a routine service, intense smell of petrol is felt while starting the  vehicle and the mileage dropped drastically from 16km/L to 12 Km/L.
What could be the probable reasons?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the miles on the vehicle? Do you use the same petrol station every time you fill up? Could be a lot of different things.

One possible reason is that a crooked employee siphons a gallon can off the tank of each vehicle. Another possible reason is they leave the engine running with no mileage, the mpg being assessed by the trip computer.

Not familiar with this particular car, but:
What could have went wrong when the service people pretend to service your car:

They may have disconnected the battery for a while and the ECU "forgot" the injection trimming data. This will fix itself after a while and the smell will also go away.

Same as the above, but the computer is out of tank calibration data so it shows wrong mileage (while in fact working correctly). This will also fix itself after a while.

They may have broken or replaced with a faulty one the exhaust oxygen sensor.

They may have drained some gasoline.

Your car may have an gasoline leak. In this case, you will get a gasoline smell before starting.

Misaligned air filter.

Miswired something around the engine.

Improper type of engine oil (but the economy difference is way too high for this)


etc, etc...

I'm not familiar with the Nexon, but on most cars the reason would be that someone damaged or disconnected the vacuum line (a thin rubber tube) going to the fuel canister relief valve.  This valve opens at startup for a brief second to ventilate the charcoal "evap" canister that collects petrol fumes from the gas tank.  With the vacuum line open, you will smell the fumes.  With the drop in vacuum pressure, the engine will such too much air and burn too much fuel.
Have a look under the hood to see if an thin rubber tubes are disconnected or broken.  With the engine running, listen for a hissing sound that could point to the faulty vacuum line/rubber tube.
